# telerik report don't show number in persian

Tags: c#, telerik, culture, telerik-reporting

I use telerik report in my application .I set culture 'fa-IR'. in my data source when the property is decimal it shows number in Persian mode but if property are string it shows number in English 
I can't changed the property type because it have anther char

I want all numeric Character in Persian mode what can i do?

Comment: If it is string, then you can replace all numeric characters with persian numbers equivalent using a simple method

Comment: how can replace them?can you show me example?

Answer (score 1):

If your property is string, you just need to replace numbers with persian numbers equivalent using a simple method. Here is a simple extension method that you can use.

```
public string ToPersianNumber(this string s)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dictionary.Add("0", "٠");
    dictionary.Add("1", "١");
    dictionary.Add("2", "٢");
    dictionary.Add("3", "٣");
    dictionary.Add("4", "٤");
    dictionary.Add("5", "٥");
    dictionary.Add("6", "٦");
    dictionary.Add("7", "٧");
    dictionary.Add("8", "٨");
    dictionary.Add("9", "٩");
    dictionary.Aggregate(s, (current, value) => current.Replace(value.Key, value.Value)).ToString();
}
```

then use it on your property.

```
yourObject.yourProperty.ToPersianNumber();
```